# Is it possible to call templated user-defined conversion operator with explicit template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, language-lawyer, conversion-operator

Lets consider the following code (compiles successfully with *clang++ 7.0.0*, compiler arguments are `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`):

```
#include <iostream>


struct Foo
{
    template <typename Type = void>
    operator int()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};


int main()
{
    const auto i = Foo{}.operator int();

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to call such templated user-defined conversion operator with explicitly provided template arguments? The naive approach doesn't compile:

```
const auto i = Foo{}.operator int<bool>();
```

Answer (score 6):

[[temp.names](Names of template specializations)/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1):

> A template specialization can be referred to by a *template-id*:
>
> ```
> simple-template-id:
>   template-name < template-argument-listₒₚₜ >
>
> template-id:
>   simple-template-id
>   operator-function-id < template-argument-listₒₚₜ >
>   literal-operator-id < template-argument-listₒₚₜ >
>
> template-name:
>   identifier
> ```

As you can see, there is no *conversion-function-id*

```
conversion-function-id:
    operator conversion-type-id
```

mentioned in the *template-id* grammar. So the answer is no. It is not possible.