# Is it legal to prefix explicit access to a conversion function template with the 'template' keyword?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    operator T() { return T{}; }
};

int main() {
    (void) A{}.operator int();          // (A)
    (void) A{}.template operator int(); // (B)
}
```

(A) is accepted by both GCC and Clang, whereas (B) is accepted only by GCC but rejected by Clang with the following error message:

> ```
> error: expected template name after 'template' keyword in nested name specifier
>
> (void) A{}.template operator int(); // (B)
>                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Afaict, (B) should be legal, as per [[temp.names]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#5):

> A name prefixed by the keyword `template` **shall be a *template-id*** or the name shall refer to a class template or an alias template. [ *Note:* The keyword `template` may not be applied to non-template members of class templates.  — *end note* ] [ *Note:* As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix **is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary**; i.e., when the *nested-name-specifier* or the expression on the left of the `->` or `.` is not dependent on a template-parameter, or the use does not appear in the scope of a template.  — *end note* ]

and as the prohibitions governed by [[temp.names]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#4) does not apply:

> The keyword `template` is said to appear at the top level in a *qualified-id* if it appears outside of a *template-argument-list* or *decltype-specifier*.  [...] **an optional keyword** `template` appearing at the top level **is ignored**. [...]

and, at most, only state that the keyword should be ignored (but not that the program is ill-formed).

I have not found any clause in [[class.conv.fct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv.fct) or [[temp.deduct.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.conv) that conflicts with this argument.

#### Question

- Is it legal to prefix explicit access to a conversion function template with the `template` keyword?

---

<sup>I have tested and repeated the compilers' behaviour above with various GCC and Clang versions for various language standard versions, but for the scope of this question, we may focus on **GCC 10.1.0** and **Clang 10.0.0** for `-std=c++17`.</sup>

Comment: @LanguageLawyer No, this question is not about explicitly specifying template arguments to a conversion function template (which I know is not possible), but whether using the `template` keyword as above is legal or not (no matter if it has no effect or is optional).

Comment: As you cite, _A name prefixed by the keyword template **shall be a template-id**_ and my answer there shows the grammar for _template-id_ doesn't have _conversion-function-id_

Comment: But on the other hand, if a conversion function template can never be referred to by a _template-id_, I guess (B) should be illegal as per temp.names/5.

Comment: Now, after I rashly retracted my flag, I can't flag again. Feel free to close as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275983/is-it-possible-to-call-templated-user-defined-conversion-operator-with-explicit

Comment: _I think the question you link to is a different one than this one, even if the answerto it holds the key to answering this question_ The box with duplicate targets of duplicate questions says «**This question already has answers here:** _link to question[s]_» so I think it is fine if question is different but answer matches.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Ups I deleted my previous comment by mistake. I tried to emphasize that the linked answer _holds the key to answering this question_, but it doesn't fully answer it (e.g. an example with _operator-function-id_). I would be happy to close this as a dupe after an answer is posted that at least fills the gaps for this Q onto the linked answer (particularly pointing out that we have a GCC bug here), as this may not be apparent for future readers. If you would not like to post one I could post a self-answer and then mark the question for dupe-closing.

Comment: _If you would not like to post one I could post a self-answer_ I think I'm not gonna answer, so plz go ahead

Comment: @LanguageLawyer OK. Thanks for the help, the relevant Q&A link and standard reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### GCC is wrong to accept the program: a conversion function template name (conversion-function-id) is not a template-id

This is [CWG Defect Report 96](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#96), which has, as of GCC 10, has not yet been addressed. The related bug GCC ticket [55588](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55588) mentions that it is being implemented for GCC 11.

---

As is covered in the answer to [Is it possible to call templated user-defined conversion operator with explicit template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275983/is-it-possible-to-call-templated-user-defined-conversion-operator-with-explicit), a conversion function template name does not name a *template-id*; quoting the grammar from *template-id* from [[temp.names]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1):

> ```
> simple-template-id:
>   template-name < template-argument-list_opt>
>
> template-id:
>   simple-template-id
>   operator-function-id < template-argument-list_opt>
>   literal-operator-id < template-argument-list_opt>
>
> template-name:
>   identifier
> ```

Thus, as is quoted in the OP, as per [temp.names]/5, the `template` keyword may not be used to prefix the name of a conversion function template, as the latter is not a *template-id*.

It may be interesting to point out that Clang does not reject using the keyword when referring to an *operator-function-id* (which *is* a *template-id*):

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    T operator+() { return T{}; }
};

int main() {
    (void) A{}.operator+<int>();          // (A)
    (void) A{}.template operator+<int>(); // (B)
}
```

That GCC accepts the OP's program is, as covered above, a bug, as it violates [temp.names]/5.

Comment: _but I have not been able to find an open bug report_ [I reported it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96321) and [was told](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96321#c1) that there is [more general bugreport](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55588).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer thanks, I see that apparently this is [CWG DR 96](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#96) that I guess never got fully inplemented by GCC. I will update the answer accordingöy later today (when not only on my phone).