# C++ Lambda with template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

I'd like to call a lambda with const template value, in example below I should write `lambdaTemplate` correctly

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int bar, int baz>
int foo(const int depth) {
    return bar + baz + depth;
}

int main() {
    ////// call function
    cout << foo<1, 2>(10) << endl; // 13

    ///// call lambda without template value
    const auto lambda1 = [&](const int v) {
        return foo<1, 2>(v);
    };
    cout << lambda1(10) << endl; // 13

    ///// call lambda with template value
    const auto lambdaTemplate = [&]<A,B ??? >(const int v) { // <-- ERROR doesn't compile
        return foo<A,B>(v);
    };

    cout << lambdaTemplate<1,2>(10) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a compiler that does support template parameters for lambdas? This is a pretty new feature (C++20). In that case the template parameters should be similar to those of `foo`.

Comment: Yes I use C++20

Comment: Even with C++20, the template argument must be deducible (or the nice syntax is not available). Either way, if what you want is a capturing  `lambdaTemplate<1,2>(10)`, that's a non-starter.

Comment: You can get `lambdaTemplate(constant<1>, constant<2>)(10)` to work, however.

Answer (score 7):

You can define lambda like this :

```
auto lambdaTemplate = [&]<int T1, int T2>(const int v) {
    return foo<T1, T2>(v);
};
```

and call it like

```
std::cout << lambdaTemplate.operator()<1,2>(10);
```

Comment: Note that `lambdaTemplate` is not a dependent name, and you shall thus not use the `template` keyword when accessing the conversion function template. At best this is redundant, but at worst ill-formed (but accepted by some compilers nonetheless), as covered in [the following Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044894/is-it-legal-to-prefix-explicit-access-to-a-conversion-function-template-with-the).

Comment: @dfrib: The parser guides are nowadays allowed in non-dependent contexts (which I fear merely encourages the popular confusion about their purpose), so long as it is in fact a *template-id* that follows.

Comment: @DavisHerring I see, thanks. I see I even pointed this out in my self-answer to the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044894/is-it-legal-to-prefix-explicit-access-to-a-conversion-function-template-with-the), but had since forgot it; it is indeed a bit confusing (and somewhat counter-intuitive) that this is allowed.