# C++20 'familiar template' lambdas: specifying an explicit argument in function pointer conversion

Tags: c++, c++20

Assuming I have the following code in C++20, using the explicit template argument lambda functionality introduced in P0428:

```cpp
auto f = []<auto val>(int a) { printf("%d", val + a); };
```

and I need a function pointer conversion for the lambda `f` to `void(*)(int)` with an explicitly specialized value (I need an explicit C ABI linkage there, member function calls will lead to different argument passing registers), given the fact that the following code is illegal:

```cpp
using intfn = void(*)(int);
f.template operator intfn<400>(); // illegal
f.template operator()<400>(0); // legal, but not what I need: is a member function call
```

(seeing the answer to [Is it possible to call templated user-defined conversion operator with explicit template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275983/is-it-possible-to-call-templated-user-defined-conversion-operator-with-explicit))

... is there any other way to get a function pointer in the current C++ language, e.g. by using some sort of implicit conversion?

Comment: Is giving `f` static storage duration an option?

Comment: No, I think. `f` is a class object with a  templated non-static member function, the call operator, that is "bounded" to the object(`this`).  You can not convert a non-static member function to a non-member function pointer.

Comment: Correct. Even if I could 'hack around it' and make a forwarding proxy to a default-constructed instance of `f`'s type (since it is a non-capturing lambda), that would still lead to inefficient code moving all arguments around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that a non-capturing lambda is default-constructible in c++20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename F>
struct args_tuple_maker;

template <auto P, typename F, typename... Args>
auto make_function_pointer(F, std::tuple<Args...>) {
    return +[](Args... args){ F{}.template operator()<P>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
}

int main() {
    auto f = []<auto val>(int a) { printf("%d", val + a); };

    auto f_ptr = make_function_pointer<200>(f, std::tuple<int>{});

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f_ptr), void(*)(int)>, "");

    f_ptr(5);
}
```

It's not a perfect solution, but maybe as close as you can get right now. Could probably be improved to deduce the arguments from the lambda type.

Comment: Right. Having optimizations enabled in the compiler seems to indeed inline the forwarded call here and make the explicit forwarding sufficiently cheap. Unless some better implicit solution exists, I guess I'm marking this as the solution.